# Python using proxies

Tags: python, proxy

Hi I am a newbie to Python. I was using googletrans and the admin suggested to use proxies in this form. Can some explain the code below:

```
from py_translator import Translator
proxy = {
        'http': 'http://username:password@1.1.1.1:1234',
        'https': 'http://username:password@1.1.1.1:1234',
}
s = Translator(proxies=proxy).translate(text='Hello my friend', dest='es').text
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a proxy for your own application.
Then can you replace `'http://username:password@1.1.1.1:1234',`
with the username and password and IP provided by the proxy.